# Using pg_restore with a remote file

Tags: postgresql, amazon-s3, command-line, pg-restore

I'm trying to use `pg_restore` to restore my database from a remote file stored in an amazon S3 bucket.

I tried to do this : `pg_restore -c -d mydb https://myfileURL` but it doesn't work, it says there is no such file or directory. The URL is fine, it's just that it can't get the file from it.

Which makes sense somehow but how can I do such a thing then ?

Perhaps there is a way to do something like this : `https://myfileURL > dump.tmp` and then executing `pg_restore` with the created file ?

Not sure if it could be a solution but I don't want to use the AWS CLI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the file first:

```
wget https://myfileURL -O dump.tmp
pg_restore -c -d dump.tmp
```

Comment: It worked fine thanks. I didn't know this cmd, it's very useful.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PgAdmin4 I've found that if you copy & paste the script to a new SQL window the actual errors show up.